# Incrementing a variable name c++

Tags: c++

I have done some research and have found no concrete answer, Is it possible to increment a variable name and/or a file location?
Would it be possible to do somthing like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<5; i ++)
{
   name1->readName("filelocation/name1.txt");
}
```

and increase `name1` and `name1.txt` by one in every loop cycle? so in the secon loop `name1` becomes `name2`?
Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: you're looking for an array

Comment: Post semi-compilable code that illustrates what you are asking about. Names in C++ are fixed at compile-time and discarded at run-time.

Comment: Variable name - no. String literal representing your file name - yes.

Comment: If you have numbered variables from `name1` to `name5` it's usually a sign that you're doing something wrong. That's what arrays are made for.

Comment: Thank you all for your coments @Ron, how would I increment the string literal representing the file name?

Comment: You need some string parsing. Let's say make 2 variables of type `std::string` one for the full path and including name without extension. And the other is only for the extension. Then it is easy to increment the first one.

Comment: How about something like..
string name= "filelocation/name"
for(int i = 0; i<5; i ++) { 
string s = name + std::to_string(i)+".txt";

name1->readName(s); 
}

Comment: You can always set macro `#define READ_NAME(INDEX) name##INDEX->readName("filelocation/name"#INDEX".txt")` and then use it 5 times `READ_NAME(0); READ_NAME(1); READ_NAME(2); READ_NAME(3); READ_NAME(4);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Variable name - no. String literal representing your file name - yes. A simple example using the [std::to_string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string& s) {
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        foo("filelocation/name" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   char filename[200]; // Make it large enough for your needs.
   std::sprintf(filename, "filelocation/name%d.txt", i+1); 
   name1->readName(filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
std::string strExt = ".txt";
std::string strPath = "D:\\Data\\test";
std::string strFullPath = strPath + strExt;

for(int i(0); i < 5; i++){
    std::cout << strFullPath << std::endl;
    strPath[strPath.length() - 1]++;
    strFullPath = strPath + strExt;
}
```

But as you can see of the loop is a bit longer then you'll get it looping back. So to do something bigger then just increment until last character or digit then append new letter and so on...

Be precise! You are not incrementing a `variable name` but you are incrementing a variable value instead. So I am in my code incrementing the value in `strPath` not `strPath` itself ("strPath, strPati, strPatj, strPatk..."). Because c++ doesn't allow such thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should store those object in a container such as array, vector, and so on, so you access each of object using index instead of the sequence of name. Assuming you had object called `Name`, this is my alternative answer  in C++ way:

```
std::vector<Name> name;
int N = 3;

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << "filelocation/name" << i << ".txt";
    img.push_back(Name());
    img[i].readName(ss.str());
}
```